# What does BinaryReader do if the bytes I am reading aren't present yet?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, binaryreader

I am using a BinaryReader on top of a NetworkStream to read data off of a network. This has worked really well for me, but I want to understand what's going on behind the scenes, so I took a look at the documentation for BinaryReader and found it to be extremely sparse.

My question is this: What will `BinaryReader.ReadBytes(bufferSize)` do if `bufferSize` bytes are not present on the network stream when I call `ReadBytes`?

In my mind there are a few options: 
1) Read any bytes that are present on the network stream and return only that many
2) Wait until `bufferSize` bytes are present on the stream, then read
3) Throw an exception

I assume option 2 is happening, since I've never received any exceptions and all my data is received whole, not in pieces. However, I would like to know for sure what is going on. If someone could enlighten me, I would be grateful.

Comment: It will block and ensure you get the requested number of bytes.  You only get less if the stream got closed and you have read them all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it *actually* goes for hidden option 4:

- Read the data as it becomes available, looping round in the same way that you normally would do manually. It will only return a value less than the number of bytes you asked for if it reaches the *end* of the stream while reading.

This is subtly different from your option 2 as it *does* drain the stream as data becomes available - it doesn't wait until it could read all of the data in one go.

It's easy to show that it does return a lower number of bytes than you asked for if it reaches the end:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[10]);
var readData = new BinaryReader(ms).ReadBytes(100);
Console.WriteLine(readData.Length); // 10
```

It's harder to prove the looping part, without a custom stream which would explicitly *require* multiple `Read` calls to return all the data.

The documentation isn't as clear as it might be, but the return value part is at least *somewhat* helpful:

> A byte array containing data read from the underlying stream. This might be less than the number of bytes requested **if the end of the stream is reached**.

Note the final part that I've highlighted, and compare that with `Stream.Read`:

> The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested **if that many bytes are not currently available**, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached.

If you're expecting an exact amount of data and *only* that amount will be useful, I suggest you write a `ReadExactly` method which calls `Read` and throws `EndOfStreamException` if you need more data than the stream provided before it was closed.

Comment: Thanks for the detail in your response. I do have one quick, easy question though. The end of the stream is only reached if the stream is closed, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If, by “present on the stream”, you’re asking whether the method would block until the specified number of bytes are available, then it is option 2. It would only return a smaller amount of bytes if the *end* of the stream is reached.

Here is some sample code on how `BinaryReader.ReadBytes(int)` may be implemented:

```
byte[] ReadBytes(int count)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[count];
    int total = 0;
    int read = 0;

    do
    {
        read = stream.Read(buffer, read, count - total);
        total += read;
    }
    while (read > 0 && total < count);

    // Resize buffer if smaller than count (code not shown).

    return buffer;
}
```